# Writing the output of a python code to multiple rows in excel

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am trying to write the output of a python code in an excel sheet.

Here's my attempt:

```
import xlwt

wbk = xlwt.Workbook() 
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('pyt')
row =0 # row counter
col=0  # col counter
inputdata = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5)]
for c in inputdata:
    for d in c:
        sheet.write(row,col,d) 

        col +=1 
    row +=1
wbk.save('pyt.xls')

Result obtained:
1 2 3 4
      2 3 4 5

Desired result
row1:  1 2 3 4 
row2:  2 3 4 5
```

Any ideas on how to get the desired result? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing that behaviour because you're not setting `col` back to zero at the end of the row.

Instead, though, you should use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) which handles the incrementing for you.

```
for row, c in enumerate(inputdata):
    for col, d in enumerate(c):
        sheet.write(row,col,d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `col = 0` on the next line after `row+=1`